# SQL: Using Alias from SELECT in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, select, group-by, case-when

I am confused about the order of query process. I have thought the order run like as follows:

FROM - WHERE - GROUP BY - HAVING - SELECT - ORDER BY

But then, I was able to use a variable alias name created in the SELECT in GROUP BY. I wonder if there's an exception with using CASE WHEN but not sure.

[image: Here is the SQL query and result]

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to are the *scoping* rules of SQL, not the execution order.  These define how column and table identifiers are disambiguated in a query.  The general ordering is:

- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `SELECT`
- `ORDER BY`

In general, the area of interest are column aliases, because table aliases are only defined in the `FROM` clause.

Because only the `SELECT` defines new column aliases (apart from those in the tables referenced in the `FROM` clause), this means that none of the clauses above it in the list can use "new" aliases.

However, some database vendors have found that this is inconvenient.  In particular, these databases "extend" the standard by allowing column aliases in the `GROUP BY` and or `HAVING` clauses.  Some databases have further restrictions, so aliases are allowed, but not expressions containing aliases.

In any case, you are using a database such as Postgres, MySQL or BigQuery that allows column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is there another example of the scoping rule that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Oleole . . . I don't know what you mean by "another example".